# Azure Cli task in Azure Devops, cant output SAS token to pass it as variable in another task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

Im trying to perform an azcopy command to copy everything from one storage account to another, however, as they are in different subscriptions, my guess was to generate a sas token for each one and then perform the action.

All of this is working fine, except the sas token is not passing to the other azure cli tasks. I even tried to use the output command to explicitly pass them but in the next taskt they are empty. Can someone help me to resolve this? I never experienced anything before.

Here´s the code:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Obtain Development SAS'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(developmentAzureServiceConnection)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      set -e

      end=`date -u -d "5 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00Z'`
      developmentConnectionString=$(az storage account show-connection-string --name $(developmentStorageAccountName) --resource-group "$(developmentResourceGroup)" --output tsv)
      echo "[DEBUG]: az storage container generate-sas --account-name $(developmentStorageAccountName) --name '$web' --permissions acdmrw --expiry $end --connection-string $developmentConnectionString"
      developmentSas=$(az storage container generate-sas --account-name $(developmentStorageAccountName) --name '$web' --permissions acdmrw --expiry $end --connection-string $developmentConnectionString)
      echo "[DEBUG]: developmentSas: $developmentSas"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=developmentSas]$developmentSas"

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Obtain Shared SAS'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(sharedAzureServiceConnection)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      set -e

      end=`date -u -d "5 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00Z'`

      echo "[DEBUG]: developmentSas: $developmentSas"
      sharedConnectionString=$(az storage account show-connection-string --name $(sharedStorageAccountName) --resource-group "$(sharedResourceGroup)" --output tsv)
      echo "[DEBUG]: az storage container generate-sas --account-name $(sharedStorageAccountName) --name '$web' --permissions acdmrw --expiry $end --connection-string $sharedConnectionString"
      sharedSas=$(az storage container generate-sas --account-name $(sharedStorageAccountName) --name '$web' --permissions acdmrw --expiry $end --connection-string $sharedConnectionString)
      echo "[DEBUG]: sharedSas: $sharedSas"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sharedSas;isOutput=false]$sharedSas"

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Copy $(developmentStorageAccountName) contents into $(sharedStorageAccountName)'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(developmentAzureServiceConnection)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      set -e

      echo "[DEBUG]: developmentSas: $developmentSas"
      echo "[DEBUG]: sharedSas: $sharedSas"

      # Upload to blob storage
      echo "azcopy copy https://$(developmentStorageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/?$developmentSas https://$(sharedStorageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/?$sharedSas --recursive"
      azcopy copy "https://$(developmentStorageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/?$developmentSas" "https://$(sharedStorageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/?$sharedSas" --recursive
```

this returns with the echos of the sas tokens empty for the azcopy task

```
[DEBUG]: developmentSas: 
[DEBUG]: sharedSas:
```

I tried with and without echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=developmentSas]$developmentSas" but it is not passing between tasks.

Comment: Are you able to see the value of `developmentSas` in `Obtain Shared SAS` task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the `environment variable` or `pipeline variable` in your next step, you are not doing either. Sample YAML code:

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
    sharedSas=my-shared-sas
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sharedSas]$sharedSas"

- bash: |
    # An environment variable called 'SHAREDSAS' can be used in the downstream steps
    echo "Environment variable: $SHAREDSAS"
    # pipeline variables needs to be referenced using $()
    echo "Pipeline variable: $(sharedSas)"
    echo "I won't be evaluated: $sharedSas"
```

**Demo run:**

[image]

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cpowershell#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script) for details